# iOS Facebook FQL results

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I want to access facebook posts on public pages by Facebook FQL API. I built multiquery like this:

```
NSString *fqlPostsName = @"queryPosts";
 NSString *fqlPosts = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT post_id, created_time, message, actor_id, attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id IN %@ LIMIT 100",fbPageIDs];

 NSString *fqlPagesName = @"queryPages";
 NSString *fqlPages = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT page_id, name, pic FROM page WHERE  page_id IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #%@)",fqlPostsName];

 NSDictionary *d = @{fqlPostsName:fqlPosts,fqlPagesName:fqlPages};
 NSDictionary *requestParams = @{@"q":[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:d options:0 error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]};

 SLRequest *getRequest = [SLRequest
                          requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                          requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                          URL:requestURL parameters:requestParams];
```

When try query on facebook Graph FQL explorer, I receive perfect response with posts I wanted. But when I run same query with same input data in my iOS application, I receive result with no posts. Although in app I generate access token with only basic FB permissons, exactly as in FB graph explorer.

Has anybody any idea why I receive empty response in my app?